# Refresh token using a separate auth server?

Tags: jwt

I'd like to use JWTs for user authorization. My intention is use an auth server and an app server to keep them separate. This way my auth server will be the only JWT issuing server and the only server w/login and sign up logic.

I've recently run into this issue however - how do I refresh a user's access token if my auth server is separate?

I'd like to use middleware via node.js to check the validity of a JWT, but if it fails, I'd need to contact the auth server, present the user's refresh token, to get a new access token.

So, what's the best way to do this?
Would I use middleware to issue a remote request to get a new JWT?
It seems there's no other way, so I thought I'd check w/the community.

Comment: I would advise against JWTs, and instead use a simple opaque session token stored in an HTTPOnly cookie. Unless you have some specific need for JWTs, they're not a good replacement for traditional sessions.

Comment: I've spent almost 3 weeks on JWTs and have realized that session ids. are easier to maintain, provide security benefits over JWTs, and are just plain simpler. That being said, I'm a bit of a principled guy and now I'm determined to see this through. I'm confident I resolved it tonight, just looking for clarity on how best to refresh an access-token when you have a remote auth server. I'm doing it via an endpoint, which appears to work fine ... but wanted the best practice (if it exists). Thanks!

Comment: Who is doing the refreshing in the scenario? Does the client have both the access token *and* the refresh token? If that's the case, you might as well just make your access token non-expiring.

Comment: Yes, the client is provided both a refresh-token that expires in 7 days and an access-token that expires in 15 minutes. How else would the client get the refresh-token to make access-token refresh requests?

Comment: user9998: would really like your input on this. the client uses a refresh-token to refresh access-tokens, providing me  an ability to revoke the refresh token and thus deny the user further access after his/her access-token expires (in this case: 15 minutes max time).

Comment: It sounds like you're over-optimizing for performance at the cost of security and complexity. A traditional session token, stored in an HTTPOnly cookie, allows you to *instantly* revoke a session, with no sliding 15 minute window where an attacker can continue to wreak havoc against you with no ability on your end to stop them.

Comment: Access tokens and refresh tokens are typically used when you want to delegate authentication to a 3rd part via something like OAuth, and in OAuth you would *never* expose the refresh token to the client, it lives on your server. You don't *need* access/refresh tokens to have your own frontend talk to your own backend.

Comment: We can also use refresh and access tokens to do as I've outlined. They aren't only for third parties services. I could have more appropriately named my access token an id token, but since I'm not using oauth, using the nomenclature "access token" is okay for my purpose. Furthermore, access and refresh tokens are indeed provided to a user in the configuration I described. In fact, it's paramount the user have the refresh token or he/she would need to re-login every 15 mins.

Comment: I prefer sessions for auth. as well, but my goal is to fully appreciate and understand jwts since I've gone down this rabbit hole. What I've realized in this journey is the lack of understanding most folks have re:jwts and auth. as they've never implemented an auth. system themselves.

Comment: Lots of people have implemented auth systems and still don't know how to do it well. They either never open up their system for peer review or it never comes under serious attack, in any case the (often glaringly obvious) flaws are never pointed out to them.